# Make a soft link ONLY resolvable as softlink

Tags: symlink

We have a 3rd party backup tool that is resolving a soft link (ORACLE_HOME) to the full physical path. It then can't find the DB as it's value of ORACLE_HOME doesn't match SAP/Oracle's version.

I.e. we have a symbolic link /oracle/SAP/122 which actually points at /oracle/SAP/12201. SAP and Oracle believe that ORACLE_HOME is /oracle/SAP/122 but the 3rd party tool picks up a value of /oracle/SAP/12201.

The way SAP works with these symbolic links mean we can't change anything from that side.

Just wondering if there's a way to 'make' the 3rd party tool only pick up the symbolic link - we can't alter the internals of the tool, is there anything we can do with the link itself or a setting in the OS? I know there are shell settings you can adjust so pwd and other commands read it as physical or symbolic but I don't know how this 3rd party tool works. Would it make any difference if we made it a hard link perhaps?

Thanks
Ross

Comment: Is the target of the link a directory? If so you can not make it a hard link, as hard links are only available for files.

Comment: Yes it is a directory - good point!

Comment: are you on linux? then you may use bind mounts instead of symlinks: `mount -B  /oracle/SAP/12201 /oracle/SAP/122` (it works even with regular files, not just directories).

Comment: Yes RHEL - that's an interesting idea and in theory should work. I believe some 'side effects' of using bind mounts though is that backups/copies/file searches etc will find both copies which could potentially cause some issues

Comment: Well everything is bound to have "side-effects" if it has any effect at all. The safest thing you could do is to modify that 3rd party tool (either recompile or do a hard-hack, ie modify the binary directly). Firefox has the same problem with symlinks when handling the file:/// protocol, and there is a `LD_PRELOAD` hack floating around -- you probably could use something similar; FWIW, include the output of `strace -fe trace=file -o str-out your_binary; grep SAP/122 str-out` in your question.